# authenticate angularJs app using wordpress site users

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

i've a desktop site based on wordpress.
Mobile version is on a subdomain and is developed using angularJs (ionic).
I'm trying to figure out what the best solution to authenticate mobile version users using wordpress wp_users credentials.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

1 - [Basic Auth](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth): The easiest, This one is not recommended for production since your users will be sending their credentials with each request, only use it over https.

2 - [OAuth](https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1/): This one is secured but might not be interesting because users will be redirected to WP to login then redirected back after login success, here is a decent [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-setting-up-and-using-oauth-10a-authentication--cms-24797) for it.

3 - [JWT Auth](https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth): This one is interesting because it only sends user credentials once, when login succeed you will get a jwt token which will be used instead of user's password in each request.

For your app purpose I recommend implementing your own authentication method, make a plugin for that, it should generate a secret token and save it in user session, it should also block any request that doesn't include that secret token.